# Flutter : When a textfield keyboard pop up the page pop out and get back to the previous page

Tags: flutter, keyboard, popup, textfield, back

I am using a simple code to have textfield in my app, but when clicking to edit the text, the keyboard pop up and then I get back to the previous page automatically.

this is my text field code:

```
TextField(

                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,

                controller: captionController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Write a caption",
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: dividerColor),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: tabColor)),
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: dividerColor)),
                ),
              ),
```

do you have an idea what's wrong?

Comment: Please provide code where `Navigator.of(context).pop()` or `context.pop()` gets called - this should be checked.

My guess is that you have a callback on Focus Change, that fires